# draw arrowline under a text string with css styles

Tags: css, cascade, underline

text-decoration-line css has underline, overline to decorate a text string. But I want further, a underline should have an arrow pointing to either left or right. It seems using text-decoration-line could not fulfill this task.

I want to highlight my string like this:

```
  THIS-IS-A-CHALLENGE-TIME                            
            -------->
```

The arrowed underline should be  associated with the words. In the example above,  I want to underline CHALLENGE word with underline pointing to right.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `border-bottom: 2px solid black;` to replace `text-decoration` for underline, and use `:after` for the head of arrow.

```css
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.arrow:after {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -6px;
    content: ">";
    bottom: -9px;
}
```

```html
THIS-IS-A-<span class="arrow">CHALLENGE</span>-TIME
```

Comment: Thank you. I read your suggested border-bottom but do not know to add arrow. You are great!